# No se insertan todos los datos de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Resulta que tengo una tabla con 3 valores: `codigo`, `rollo`, `cantidad`, esta consta de 20k registros pero la mayoria tiene la cantidad en 0, entonces con el siguiente query quiero ver cuantos no estan en 0:

```
SELECT*FROM Casiller WHERE cantidad>0
```

Me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En total tengo 302 registros mayores a 0, ahora quiero pasar, estos registro junto con otros a otra tabla, lo cual empleo este query:

**TABLA DE DESTINO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
INSERT INTO RUbicacion(cod_parte, rollo, descripcion, unidad)
  SELECT ca.cod_parte,
         ca.rollo,
         pa.descripcion,
         pa.unidad
  FROM Casiller ca
  INNER JOIN Partes pa ON pa.cod_parte=ca.cod_parte
  WHERE ca.cantidad>0
```

Lo añade a la table nueva, pero solo me añade esta cantidad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en el `WHERE` le estoy diciendo que agregue solo mayores a 0 por que no agrega contiene el mismo tamaño que el anterior?

Comment: Toma encuenta que estás haciendo un INNER JOIN...

Comment: has el select antes, mira si los registros cumplen las condiciones para ser ingresados

Comment: @Dionicio cual es el problema con el `INNER JOIN` aqui? (Pregunto por que no se)

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si ejecuto el `SELECT` primero me da 299

Comment: Puede que en hayan datos que no coincidan en los campos 'cod_parte' de tu tabla 'Casiller' con 'cod_parte' de la tabla 'Partes'. Como dice @IgmerRodriguez prueba ejecutando el select junto con el INNER JOIN aparte.

Comment: primero prueba con SELECT distinct(cod_parte) FROM Casiller WHERE cantidad>0   asi sabras cuantos codigos parte distintos  tienes y no son los 300 que dices estoy seguro

Comment: Si quieres pasar datos de una tabla a otra, ¿por que usar INNER JOIN?. ¿Has probado hacer lo mismo sin ese INNER JOIN?

Comment: @MiguelZarate pasa que la tabla `Casiller` tiene datos repetidos en la columna `cod_parte` por ejemplo, existe el #123 pero este tiene distinto numero de rollos

Comment: @Youshiro por que necesito rescatar valores como descripcion y unidad, por ejemplo el `cod_parte` #123 puede tener una descripcion de "tela" y puede tener una unidad de "mts", entonces necesito guardar esos datos en la nueva tabla, de ahi el `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Que tipo de dato es tu atributo "cantidad"?

Comment: @BrandonCastillo float

Comment: No todas las entradas de Casiller tienen entrada en Partes.

Comment: Hay tres filas en `Casiller` que no se encuentran en `Partes`, para saber cuales son estás: `SELECT * FROM Casiller ca LEFT JOIN Partes pa ON pa.cod_parte=ca.cod_parte WHERE ca.cantidad>0 and pa.cod_parte is null`. ¿La pregunta que es lo que deberías hacer con estas filas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude resolver cambiando `INNER JOIN` por `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO RUbicacion(cod_parte, rollo, descripcion, unidad)
  SELECT ca.cod_parte,
         ca.rollo, 
         pa.descripcion,
         pa.unidad
  FROM Casiller ca
  FULL OUTER JOIN Partes pa ON pa.cod_parte=ca.cod_parte
  WHERE ca.cantidad>0
```

Comment: El `FULL OUTER JOIN` puede ser excesivo y sólo debe usarse cuando realmente se requiera. Por lo general, con un buen diseño un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` es suficiente.